# Select element if contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this one to work and I can't find any similar question that does the same what I want.

I have a table with rows like this:

```
<div class="gui-table">
          <table>
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><p class="customfields">Size</p></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
           //etc...
```

I want to check if all the second cells have the **text** "size" in it! If so then hide the third `td`.

So what I thought what would work is this:

```
 $('.gui-table tr').each(function(){

  if ($('td:nth-child(2) .customfields:contains("Size")').length > 0) {
     $(this).css('visibillity', 'hidden');
   }
 });
```

This doesn't work! Does anybody see what is wrong with this?

Comment: "visibility" is misspelled (two l). Also, you say you want to hide the third cell of the row but $(this), which you're hiding, will represent the row element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to hide the third column, when there is the word 'size' in the second one you can do this in that way:

```
$('.gui-table td:nth-child(2):contains("Size")').next().css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0qczvak5/

**The explanation:**

Select all elements with the class name `.gui-table`, select all second `td`s with `td:nth-child(2)`, filter them with `:contains("Size")`. Now you have all second `td`s with the word "Size" and with `.next()` you get the following cell (the third one) and you hide it with `.css('visibility', 'hidden')`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$('.gui-table .customfields:contains("Size")').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfmrngcc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly the following should do it:

```js
$('.gui-table p.customfields:contains("Size")').parent().next().hide();
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gui-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Shown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><p class="customfields">Size</p></td>
      <td>Hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

This will hide the next table cell after any table cell containing a p tag with the text Size.

It works by finding the P tags [containing](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) size inside the gui-table - `$('.gui-table p.customfields:contains("Size")')`

Then using [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select it's parent table cell.

And finally [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) to select the next table cell and hide it.

Answer (score 1):

I banged around on this and came up with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JayAChTee/vs84pmu9/) that should get you going again.  The essential function is much like you started with but modified like this:

```
    function doItNow(e)
    {
        $('.gui-table tr').each(function ()
        {
            $('td:nth-child(2) .customfields:contains("Size")').each(function ()
            {
                $(this).parents('tr').children('td:nth-child(3)').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
        });
    }
```

Note that the inner each() is passing the paragraph element and not the cell element.  So I traversed up the parents() chain until I find the row and hide the 3rd child.  You might be able to code this without the inner each but I am too lazy to be that complicated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gui-table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(
    function (index,tag){  
        if ($(tag).find("p").text() == "Size") 
        $(tag).css('visibility', 'hidden');
   }
 )
```

This is will work .